# Identify Invalid Azure Container Names

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How can one programmatically determine if a container name is invalid per the rules?

---

Valid naming for a Container in Azure Blob Storage.

1. 3 to 63 Characters
2. Starts With Letter or Number
3. Letters, Numbers, and Dash (-)
4. Every Dash (-) Must Be Immediately Preceded and Followed by a Letter or Number
5. All letters in a container name must be lowercase.

Comment: Somone woke up in the wrong side of the bed this morning?

Comment: Use standard validation, which throws an exception if invalid:
`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.NameValidator.ValidateContainerName(myContainerName)` ([related discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d364761b-6d9d-4c15-8353-46c6719a3392/what-regular-expression-could-i-use-to-validate-a-blob-container-name?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d364761b-6d9d-4c15-8353-46c6719a3392/what-regular-expression-could-i-use-to-validate-a-blob-container-name?forum=windowsazuredata))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Valid naming for a Container in Azure Blob Storage.

1. 3 to 63 Characters
2. Starts With Letter or Number
3. Letters, Numbers, and Dash (-)
4. Every Dash (-) Must Be Immediately Preceded and Followed by a Letter or Number
5. All letters in a container name must be lowercase.

In my WebAPI i used the following:

```
        if (container.Length < 3 ||
            container.Length > 63 ||
            !Regex.IsMatch(container, @"^[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*$"))
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid Request!"));
```

Comment: And... just in case anyone's looking for the MSDN article reference (which also includes blob naming rules), it's [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135715.aspx).

Comment: A bit late to the party but you can just use a single regex: ^[a-z0-9]{3,63}$

Comment: And how does yours cover dashes?

Comment: The one in my answer covers dashes.

Comment: There's a another solution to that that covers all cases in a single regex and also has a bonus of $root (nice Easter egg from Azure storage team). Link:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d364761b-6d9d-4c15-8353-46c6719a3392/what-regular-expression-could-i-use-to-validate-a-blob-container-name?forum=windowsazuredata

Comment: I came up with an easier to read single regex but could not reply as an answer so I put it up on my blog [Identify Invalid Azure Container Names Using .Net Regex](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1223).

Comment: Why would azure make '$web' as default if it is not a valid storage name?